# Finding the Nth Smallest number, How to fix my method "int minNumber(int[] numbers, int selected)"?

Tags: java

I just want to code a method to find Nth smallest number, there are many ways to do it but I want to write it in a different way.
When I call my method like this, it shows me not correct result

```
int[] numbers = {200, 700, 11, 4, 10, 6, 19, 40};
System.out.println(minNumber(numbers, 7));
```

when I try to reach 7th and 8th smallest number it is not gonna work! :(
I do not know how to fix the main problem I mean if I change my array to another array with different range.
**Note**: It has to work with every possible integer array.

```java
static int minNumber(int[] numbers, int selected) {
  if(numbers == null || numbers.length <= 0) return -1;
  int intReturn = 0;
  int[] intMinNumbers = new int[numbers.length];
  int intFound = 0;
  for(int s=0; s<=selected; s++) {
    intReturn = numbers[0];
    System.out.println("-loop: "+s);
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
      boolean scape = false; //I think my problem is inside this loop below. from here
      for(int min=0; min<=intFound; min++) {
        if(intMinNumbers[min] != 0 && numbers[i] == intMinNumbers[min]) {
          scape = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(scape) continue; // to here
      if(numbers[i] < intReturn) {
        intReturn = numbers[i];
        System.out.println("--"+intReturn);
      }
    }
    intMinNumbers[s] = intReturn;
    intFound++;
  }
  return intReturn;
}
```

This is the output when I run my code :_

```
-loop: 0
--11
--4
-loop: 1
--11
--10
--6
-loop: 2
--11
--10
-loop: 3
--11
-loop: 4
--19
-loop: 5
--40
-loop: 6 // <--this part is wrong
-loop: 7 // <--this part is wrong
200      // <--this part is wrong
but I expect this, to show it to me
-loop: 0
--11
--4
-loop: 1
--11
--10
--6
-loop: 2
--11
--10
-loop: 3
--11
-loop: 4
--19
-loop: 5
--40
-loop: 6
--200
-loop: 7
700
```

Comment: please "comment" your program a little... maybe you'll be able to identify problems yourself, but main (re-)questions: "Smallest number" means "0th" or "1st" - smallest? (selected is 0 or 1 based) ...  If it is zero-based, why would you do `selected+1` iterations? ..and if it is 1-based, why would you expect output `700`? (it is the 8th smallest number (of 8)).

Comment: Yes sure, it is not so important in which case the first loop gonna work, because I can simply change this line `for(int s=0; s<=selected; s++) {` to `for(int s=1; s<=selected; s++) {` and change this line `intMinNumbers[s] = intReturn;` to `intMinNumbers[s-1] = intReturn;` it is not so important. The main problem is inside the second loop. I do not know which part and I tried every possible code which I could but I could not. And this method has go through every small number until it found { Nth } small number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final answer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {200, 700, 11, 4, 10, 6, 19, 40};
    System.out.println(minNumber(numbers, 7));
}

static int minNumber(int[] numbers, int selected) {
  if(numbers == null || numbers.length <= 0) return -1;
  int intReturn = 0;
  int[] intMinNumbers = new int[numbers.length];
  int intFound = 0;
  for (int s = 0; intFound < numbers.length && s < selected; s++) {// this line changed
    intReturn = Integer.MAX_VALUE;// this line changed
    System.out.println("-loop: "+s);
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
      boolean scape = false;
      for(int min=0; min<=intFound; min++) {
        if(intMinNumbers[min] != 0 && numbers[i] == intMinNumbers[min]) {
          scape = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(scape) continue;
      // instead of checking largest number maybe there is another way
      // this line was my main problem
      if(numbers[i] < intReturn) {
        intReturn = numbers[i];
        System.out.println("--"+intReturn);
      }
    }
    intMinNumbers[s] = intReturn;
    intFound++;
  }
  return intReturn;
}
```

This is the output when I run my code :_

```
-loop: 0
--11
--4
-loop: 1
--11
--10
--6
-loop: 2
--11
--10
-loop: 3
--11
-loop: 4
--19
-loop: 5
--40
-loop: 6
--200
-loop: 7
700
```

And you can use every possible array of numbers but for very large numbers you have to change integer array to double or using a resizable array.

Answer (score 0):

In the outer for loop the variable inReturn is not assigned as the largest number in your array, try changing `intReturn = numbers[0];` to `intReturn = numbers[1];`. I haven't tested it, but it seems the most obvious problem.

Comment: Not correctly, because if I change that line to `intReturn = numbers[1];` it might works but temporary, I mean that array`numbers = {200, 700, 11, 4, 10, 6, 19, 40};` which I used it is an example and that problem is still exist.

Comment: perhaps you will need to write a method that returns the largest number in the array to assign to 'intReturn'. You also have other problems in your code, 1) You do not check if 'selected' is a larger int than ' numbers.length'. 2) An array index starts at a'0', this means your 'selected' array index will be one less than the selected number. So your for loop should be 's < selected' rather than 's <= selected', you could get an out of bounds error with the latter.

Comment: Thanks and checked it and it would work if I assign `intReturn = 800`, because in this line `if(numbers[i] < intReturn) {` my logic is working in a wrong way! I think. And for this particular line `s < selected' rather than 's <= selected` there is no problem, and I should check my `selected` variable too.